# Find all solutions, other than $2$ for $12x^3-23x^2-3x+2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all solutions, other than $2$ for $12x^3-23x^2-3x+2=0$

I started off by taking out an $x$ and got $$x(12x^2-23x-3)+2=0$$
I do not know if this is the correct first step, if it is, then am I able to use the quadratic formula or complete the square to get the answers. Can anyone give me general hints. Please **do not** solve this for me in anyway. Just give me hints.

Comment: That first step doesn't work very well. It's good if you can find something to factor out of the *entire* expression so that you end up with something like $AB=0$, because then you can break up the problem into "$A=0$ or $B=0$". But changing it to $AB+C=0$ does not usually simplify the problem.

Comment: The step is technically not incorrect. But it is *not at all* useful.

Comment: Since $12x^2-23x-3$ at $x=2$ is $-1$, then $x=2$ is a solution of the polynomial. Then divide the original polynomial by $x-2$ to get a quadratic which can be easily solved for the other roots 1/4 and -1/3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

The great bit here is to note that $2$ is a solution. By the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), we know that the linear factor $(x - 2)$ divides our polynomial.

So perhaps you should divide out $(x-2)$. You'll be left with a quadratic, which we know how to solve very quickly.

Comment: So, I synthetically divide and then use the quadratic formula for the rest?

Comment: That sounds like a great strategy to me. Good luck!

Comment: I'll recomment with my answer and hopefully it'll be right! Thanks for the help!

Comment: $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Austin: You don't need to ask. You could just plug in those values and check whether they satisfy your equation.

Comment: @Austin: We know how to check our answer, too: we plug in our values and see if the polynomial gives $0$. I noticed that these values, $-1/4$ and $1/2$, don't. So perhaps you should recheck your math?

Comment: @Austin: Hey that's great! Although, unless my math is off, I happen to get $1/4$ and $-1/3$, as if one of us dropped a negative somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The preceding answers have provided you with sufficient information. However the following might help you with future endeavors:

**How would you factor the polynomial if 2 *wasn't* given as a root?**

There exists a useful theorem: the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), that helps
factor polynomials (indirectly). It gurantees that *any* root of the polynomial will have a numerator that has $c$, the constant, as a factor and a denominator that has $a_n$, the leading coefficient, as a factor.

Therefore by investigating all possible conbinations of the factors of the constant and the factors of the leading coefficient you can eventually arrive at a valid root. The polynomial can then be further factored into a quadratic through synthetic division which can be factored (as you know) through the quadratic formula.

The interesting thing about this method is its large scope of applicability: it not only works on cubic polynomials but on a polynomial with *any* degree.

Answer (score 2):

The reciprocals of the roots $\rm\,r,s,1/2\:$ are roots of the reversed polynomial $\rm\:2\, x^3\! -\! 3\, x^2\! -\! 23\, x\! +\! 12.\: $ Thus by Vieta's Formulas $\rm\:r\!+\!s\!+\!1/2 = 3/2,\ rs/2 = -6,\:$ so $\rm\:r\!+\!s = 1,\ rs = -12,\:$ so $\rm\:r,s = \ldots$

Alternatively, by the Factor Theorem, $\rm\:f(2) = 0\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:f(x)\:$ has $\rm\:x\!-\!2\:$ as a factor. Comparing coef's

$$\rm (x-2)(a\, x^2 + b\, x + c)\ =\ 12\, x^3 - 23\,x^2 -3\,x + 2$$

$\rm\qquad x^3\:$ coef $\rm\:\Rightarrow\: a = 12$

$\rm\qquad x^0\:$ coef $\rm\:\Rightarrow\: -2\,c = 2\:\Rightarrow\: c = -1$

$\rm\qquad x^1\:$ coef $\rm\:\Rightarrow\: -3 = c-2b = -1-2b\:\Rightarrow\: b = 1 $

So the quadratic factor is $\rm\: 12\,x^2 + x - 1,\:$ which can be solved by either the Quadratic Formula or Rational Root Test, or $\rm\:(c\,x\!-\!1)\,(d\,x\!+\!1) = 12\,x^2\!+\!x\!-\!1\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:cd=12,\ c\!-\!d = 1,\:$ so $\rm\:c,d = \ldots$

Comment: $c=4$ and $d=3$?

Comment: @Austin Indeed, they satisfy the equations.